# Javascript async function not executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, pdfjs-dist

I am making a website that reads pdf files and filters through them. For this I am using `React JS` for the front end and `pdfjs-dist` to read the pdfs.

I have a file App.jsx that has the components. And a file pdfReader.js that contains the functions for reading the pdfs.

The problem essentially is that lines that contain the `await` keyword dont execute, and neither do any of the lines below the await line in a given function.

When I test pdfReader.js on it's own, it successfully reads and filters the pdfs. When the function `filterURLs()` (from pdfReader.js) is called in App.jsx, nothing happens. After using log statements to debug, I found that the function call simply doesnt do anything after the first await statement in the function.

for example:

```
filterURLs(keyword, fileList).then(
        (fiteredLinks) => { console.log(fiteredLinks) }
   )
```

`filterURLs` returns a list of URL strings.

And here it is in pdfReader.js:

```
export async function filterURLs(word, urlArray) {
  console.log("FILTERING THE URLS.....");
  const newFileArr = [];
  for (let i = 0, len = urlArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (await checkPDF(word, urlArray[i])) {
      newFileArr.push(urlArray[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log("Filtered URLs:", newFileArr); // Log the filtered URLs

  return newFileArr
}
```

which calls these functions:

```
export async function getContent(src) {
  try {
    const doc = await getDocument(src).promise; 
// Based on log statements that i have ommitted from the code for readability, the function stops executing from the above line (and the error message doesnt print either)
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("GET DOCUMENT ERROR");
    }
    const page = await doc.getPage(1);

    const content = await page.getTextContent();

    const items = content.items.map(item => item.str);
    const text = items.join(' '); // Join all the items into a single string
    return text;
  }




export async function checkPDF(word, src) {
  console.log("Checking PDF....")
    const text = await getContent(src);
    const inPDF = text.includes(word);
    console.log("DONE Checking PDF....", inPDF);
    return inPDF;
}

export async function wordInPDF(word, src) {
    return checkPDF(word, src) ? 1 : 0
}
```

I am new to Javascript and React so I dont know if I'm using await wrong or something like that. I have no idea how to fix it, as i cant read PDFs without using await. If someone could help I'd really appreciate it, and if I need to explain the problem better or show more code let me know and i will readily do so.

Here is some more code showing my implementation of App.jsx. Specifically the function FileSet to call filterURLs. FileSet does not work, and the log statements inside it does not print.

```js
function App() {
  

  const [fileUpload, setFileUpload] = useState(null);
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);

  const [nameDisplay, setNameDisplay] = useState(false);
  const [nameList, setNameList] = useState([]);


  const fileListRef = ref(storage, `files/`)

  const uploadFile = () => {
    if (fileUpload === null) return;
    const fileRef = ref(storage, `files/${fileUpload.name}`);
    uploadBytes(fileRef, fileUpload).then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
        setFileList((prevFileList) => [...prevFileList, url]);
        setNameList((prevNameList) => [...prevNameList, fileUpload.name]);
        console.log("file uploaded");
      });
    });
  };
// could potentially implement filtration here in the useeffect
  useEffect(() => {
    listAll(fileListRef).then((response) => {
      const urls = [];
      const names = [];
      response.items.forEach((item) => {
        getDownloadURL(item).then((url) => {
          urls.push(url);
          names.push(item.name);
          if (urls.length === response.items.length) {
            setFileList(urls);
            setNameList(names);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }, []);

  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");
  const [submittedWord, setSubmittedWord] = useState("");

  const handleSumbission = (item) => {
    console.log("submission handled: ", item)
    setFilteredFiles(["HANDLED"]);
  }

  const [filteredFiles, setFilteredFiles] = useState([]);
  const [filteredNames, setFilteredNames] = useState([]);

  const [bitmap, setBitmap] = useState([]);

    async function FileSet(keyword, fileList) {
      console.log("setting files...")
      console.log("fileList: ", fileList);
      filterURLs(keyword, fileList).then(
        (filterURLsResult) =>
        {
        console.log("filterURLsResult = ", filterURLsResult)
        }
      )

    }

    async function NameSet(keyword, fileList, nameList) {
      setFilteredNames(await filterNAMEs(keyword, fileList, nameList));
    }

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="header">Resume Finder</h1>

    <SearchBar value={keyword} onSubmit={(e) => {
      setSubmittedWord(keyword)

      FileSet(keyword, fileList);
      NameSet(keyword, fileList, nameList);

      e.preventDefault();

}} onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)} />


        <KeyDisplay keyword={submittedWord} heading="Keyword:"></KeyDisplay>

          <UploadFile onClick={uploadFile} onChange={(event) => {
              setFileUpload(event.target.files[0]);
            }}></UploadFile>

            <ResDisplay nameDisplay={nameDisplay} nameList={filteredNames} fileList={filteredFiles} onShow={() => setNameDisplay(true)} onHide={() => setNameDisplay(false)}></ResDisplay>
            {/* <ResDisplay nameDisplay={nameDisplay} nameList={nameList} fileList={fileList} onShow={() => setNameDisplay(true)} onHide={() => setNameDisplay(false)}></ResDisplay> */}
          
        </div>
  );


}


export default App;
```

Comment: There's a few things wrong with your code, but it's hard to tell if they're related to your problem. `const doc` is defined inside the `try {}` so it's not accessible outside the try. `await getDocument(src).promise;` looks weird, why are you accessing `.promise` ? Without seeing `getDocuments()` it's hard to know if that's right. And `return checkPDF(word, src) ? 1 : 0` should be `return (await checkPDF(word, src)) ? 1 : 0`. And please get in the habit of reading Javascript errors, don't ignore them!

Comment: And what does `getDocument(src).promise` do?

Comment: One problem is that because `doc` is declared within the try block it isn’t in scope (doesn’t exist) in the code below the catch. I’d expect the `await doc.getPage(1);` call to blow up.

Comment: @AndyRay Thing is, I didn't get any error messages. And `getDocuments()` is a method from `pdfjs-dist`. When I run the file with these PDF functions individually, it works perfectly, its only when I call `filterURLs` in App.jsx that stuff stops working.

Comment: @ghybs it is a method from pdfjs-dist library that returns the PDF document. Not sure exactly what, I followed a tutorial to read the pdfs using this library.

Comment: @ghybs @AndyRay Without the `.promise` at the end of getDocuments, it doesnt work. must be a library-specific thing

Comment: The code works is the frustrating bit. It breaks when called in a different file -- that's what i dont get

Comment: Wait, could it be because of some obscure Node.js thing? or because app is a .jsx file? i ran the function i used in App.jsx in another .js file and it worked fine

Answer (score -1):

From the information that you've provided you are exporting the functions from pdfReader.js as named exports. In the App.jsx you need to import them as : 
**import { filterURLs } form 'respective-path';**
If you did the same please provide the code that you have written in App.jsx.

Comment: Yes, I imported them just like that. I have edited my post and attached my App.jsx code that calls filterURLs.